# What's so wrong with pointy shoes?

Tags: witches, wardstone-chronicles

In the very first book of the *[Wardstone Chronicles](http://www.spooksbooks.com/)*, the Spook warns Tom not to trust girls in pointy shoes.  I assume this advice is given, as most witches wear pointy shoes (although his Mam, who is a witch, does not wear pointy shoes).  So my question is: is there anything wrong with pointy shoes in themselves, or are they just a sign?

Comment: Do you want to know what's wrong with pointy shoes (as your title indicates) or why witches wear pointy shoes (as your question body indicates)?  Those are two separate questions; pick one.

Comment: I quite liked this question. There was a canon answer and plenty of material in the books relating to the subject.

Comment: The question has just been edited - please re-consider if this, in your opinion, is a more specific question.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the [Wardstone Chronicle](http://www.spooksbooks.com/index.asp) books, spooks and witches are relatively commonplace and are generally viewed with suspicion by the general public. Various characters describe them as causing "mischief", tricking men into falling in love with them, cursing the innocent, "robbing graves", stealing life-force, shape-shifting, being "little more than animals", etc etc etc.

That said, they aren't *universally* disliked and the pointy shoes that they characteristically wear allow them to be identified by non-witches seeking their services (such as the landlord below from '[The Spooks Destiny](http://www.spooksbooks.com/spooksdestiny.asp)') as well as by other witches.

> “You are a spook, aren’t you?” The landlord suddenly glanced down at
>   Alice’s pointy shoes and looked a little doubtful.
>
> Women and girls who wore pointy shoes were often suspected of being
>   witches. That was certainly true of Alice; she’d received two years’
>   training from her mother, Lizzie the bone witch. She was my close
>   friend, and we’d been through a lot together—Alice’s magic had saved
>   my life more than once—but my master was always concerned that one day
>   she might drift back toward the dark. He frowned at her briefly, then
>   turned back to the innkeeper. “Aye, I’m a spook, and this is my
>   apprentice, Tom Ward. The girl’s called Alice—she works for me,
>   copying books and doing other chores. Why don’t you tell me why you
>   need my services?”

[image: Alice Pointy Shoes]